# Can I use a valid email address as a linux directory name

Tags: linux, email, language-agnostic

I thought this would have been asked a million times already, but my search didn't turn up anything.

Can I safely use an email address as a linux directory name? In other words is any valid email address also a valid directory name? If not are there any characters in particular that I would have to filter first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, almost.

The `'/'` character is allowed in emails (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax) but not in linux filenames.

See SO Answer here: [Are there any invalid linux filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311037/are-there-any-invalid-linux-filenames)