# How to append string after matching field with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to append a word after `<body>` tag, it should not modify/replace anything other than just append a word. I have done something like this, is it valid do empty parenthesis fir second capture group will match everything?

```
/(<body[^>]*>)()/, `$1${my_variable}$2`)
```

Comment: In what context are you doing this? Matching HTML with RegEx is typically frowned upon if it can be avoided.

Comment: beside the previous comment, all you care about is finding the body. The rest won't be changed so that `/(<body[^>]*>)/, '$1' + my_variable` would be enough

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi ohk,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second capture group, designed to capture nothing, will match "nothing" - it will form a match immediately after your closed body tag. There's nothing wrong with doing this for the regex, though you might want to be wary of using `[^>]*` - this negated character class will gladly match across lines and grab as much input as it can. Handy for matching multi-line tags, but often very dangerous.

Also, if you're on linux and for some reason have `>` symbols in filenames [(which is valid!)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1311070/7431860) your regex will break horribly, [as shown here.](https://regex101.com/r/UwXMWB/1/)

That being said, valid regex or not, it's usually [a bad idea to use regex with html](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/), since HTML isn't a regular language. Also, you could accidentally [summon Cthulhu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7431860).

Answer (score 0):

```
let page = "<html><body>Some info</body></html>";

page.replace("<body>", `<body>${my_variable}`);
```

or

```
page.replace(/<body>|<BODY>/, `<body>${my_variable}`);
```

If in the broweser you can also use `document.querySelector("body").innerHTML`

Also depending on which framework you're using there are better ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Actually the issue is, sometimes user append space in body tag or any CSS that why it won't work